# FTP timeout but SSH is working?

Tags: ftp, fedora, timeout

I have a problem in my server, when I try to connect via FTP to a domain, the connexion is VERY slow, and I get timeouts just listing files in a directory.

When I try to connect to the domain folder using the root user account via SSH, it works fine, and I can download the files without problem.

What can be wrong? I tried to reboot the server, also the office router, and nothing...

It is a fedora core 7 server with proftpd. Can it be a filesystem problem? Thanks.

```
CONNECTION LOG:
Cmd: MLST about.php
250:  Start of list for about.php
      modify=20120910092528;perm=adfrw;size=2197;type=file;UNIX.group=505;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.owner=10089; about.php

     End of list
Cmd: PASV
227: Entering Passive Mode (***hidden***).
Data connection timed out.
Falling back to PORT instead of PASV mode.
Connection falling back to port (PORT) mode.
Cmd: PORT ***hidden***
200: PORT command successful
Cmd: RETR about.php
Could not accept a data connection: Operation timed out.
```

Comment: What mode are you using when connecting via FTP ? Is it really slow to connect via FTP (command-line) or do you just get a timeout when asking for a directory listing ?

Comment: I use paseive mode I'll add a connection log.

Comment: *pasive, sorry.

Comment: Finally, after a lot of tests, I called to the datacenter, and it seems to be a connectivity issue in the datacenter.

Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was a internal problem of our service provider, so I close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try use passive mode in ftp client.

Comment: I'm already using pasive mode, and I have a lot of domains configured in my ftp client and everything was going ok since some hours ago.

Comment: Check once more. And show iptables -L from fedora. Its totaly looks like proftpd cant open data connection.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused due a missconfiguration at your reverse DNS.

Try going to /etc/proftpd.conf

Look for

```
UseReverseDNS on
IdentLookups on
```

and change them for

```
UseReverseDNS off
IdentLookups off
```

Will let u connect faster, I bet the error message you get its conection timeout or refused by the server.

Comment: It is already off...

Comment: did you change the timeout in the proftpd configuration?

Comment: not changed, but my ftp client waits about 30 secs before getting a timeout, for download a 2KB php file...